# Methods to find reciprocating votes in rating system

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, rating-system

I have an active voting system which essentially comes down to a database table, with columns "votefrom" and "voteto".

Basically, I'm trying to work out an alert system that can detect abuse. One such case if finding a way to detect reciprocating votes (people who have the tendency to mainly vote for each other), or perhaps clusters of such votes.

The ideal outcome would be a list of users, where next to each user, there is a matched user and a percentage, showing that for instance user A is doing 10% of his votes to user B. This obviously in descending order, so that users with most tendency to vote specifically for one other user are on top.

So, my question is, would this be possible in queries alone, or how far can SQL get me?

Any pointers to existing implementations? (preferrably PHP)

Comment: SQL can get you pretty far.  Other than that, your question is too broad.  I would suggest that you delete it.  Then ask another question, providing sample data and explain what results you want to get out of it.

Comment: I edited my question with a more specific desired outcome.

Comment: what database vendor? each has different variants of sql with both capability and syntax differences. suggest you always indicate dbms if you have an sql relate question. adding "sample data" and "expected result" would go a long way to refining this question

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 GA

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example only (using MS SQL Server) but works in any SQL variant that supports **COUNT() OVER()**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   votefrom INTEGER
  ,voteto   INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,200);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,200);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,200);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,200);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,200);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,300);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,400);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,500);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,600);
INSERT INTO mytable(votefrom,voteto) VALUES (100,700);
```

**query:**

```
select distinct
       votefrom
     , voteto
     , count(*) over(partition by votefrom, voteto) fromto
     , count(*) over(partition by votefrom) fromtot
     , count(*) over(partition by votefrom, voteto) * 100 / count(*) over(partition by votefrom) pct
from mytable
```

**result:**

```
+----+----------+--------+--------+---------+-----+
|    | votefrom | voteto | fromto | fromtot | pct |
+----+----------+--------+--------+---------+-----+
|  1 |      100 |    200 |      5 |      10 |  50 |
|  2 |      100 |    300 |      1 |      10 |  10 |
|  3 |      100 |    400 |      1 |      10 |  10 |
|  4 |      100 |    500 |      1 |      10 |  10 |
|  5 |      100 |    600 |      1 |      10 |  10 |
|  6 |      100 |    700 |      1 |      10 |  10 |
+----+----------+--------+--------+---------+-----+
```

see: http://rextester.com/UESP57757

Syntax in MySQL would be quite different while that dbms does not support COUNT() OVER()

Comment: Great. I'll be using MariaDB 10.2, which supports COUNT() as a window function, so I presume it will be somewhat similar.

Comment: Yes the query above works on Maria db 10.2. This is why you need to specify such details in the question tags.